# Cocoa NSString explode

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a NSString: `@"1a,1b,1c,1d,5c"`. I want this NSString separated into a NSMutableArray, but I don't know how. I think it is fairly simple but I can't find it (maybe because my English isn't good enough to find a good description for it to search on).

Regards,
Dodo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
NSString *_stringToSplit = @"1a,1b,1c,1d,5c";
NSArray *_splitItems = [_stringToSplit componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *_mutableSplitItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_splitItems count]]; 
[_mutableSplitItems addObjectsFromArray:_splitItems];
```

Comment: What's the reason for the underlines? (Just wondering, I haven't seen that for local variables yet.)

Comment: It's just a visual indicator I use for quickly identifying local or short-lived, tightly-scoped variables.

Answer (score 8):

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`-componentsSeparatedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_) to explode.

The returned value is an NSArray. If you need an NSMutableArray, call the `-mutableCopy` method on it.